# acceder a los indices de un hash en ruby

Tags: ruby, map

Estoy haciendo un programa para eliminar los excedentes de un arreglo, si tenemos más cantidad de elementos que `maxOcurrences` las omitimos.

Por ejemplo

> [20,37,20,21] => [20,37,21]

Mi problema en concreto es para acceder a los índices de un hash, este es mi código:

```
def delete_nth(elements,maxOcurrences)
  if maxOcurrences < 1
        return []
  end
    newArray = []
    aparisons = {}
    elements.each do |element|
        occurrences = aparisons[String(element)]
        puts "a" << String(occurrences)
        if occurrences.nil?
            newArray.push(element)
            aparisons["element"]=1
            puts aparisons
        else
            puts "e" << String(occurrences)
            if occurrences < maxOcurrences
                puts "i" << String(occurrences)
                newArray.push(element)
                aparisons["element"]=occurrences + 1
                puts "j"<<aparisons
            end
        end
    end
    return newArray
end
```

Entrada

> delete_nth([20,37,20,21], 1)

Salida

> a
>   {"element"=>1}
>   a
>   {"element"=>1}
>   a
>   {"element"=>1}
>   a
>   {"element"=>1}

Cómo puedo corregirlo? De momento intento acceder a los índices mediante `aparisons[String(element)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para encontrar la llave de un *hash* (los *hash* no tienen índicies) simplemente debes utilizar el método `[]` con el nombre de la llave (ya sea un *string*, un *symbol* o un número); por ejemplo:

```
nuevo_hash = { "uno" => "Valor 1", "dos" => "Valor 2" }

nuevo_hash["uno"]
#=> "Valor 1"
```

Si buscas el nombre de una llave que no existe en el *hash* este te devolverá `nil` (o, en caso de establecerlo al crear el *hash*, un valor por defecto).

En tu código está pasando justamente lo anterior: `ocurrences` siempre será `nil` debido a que pides una llave no existente del *hash* `aparisons` en la siguiente línea:

```
occurrences = aparisons[String(element)]
```

La cual sería equivalente a las siguientes líneas (una por cada iteración del `each`):

```
occurrences = aparisons["20"]
occurrences = aparisons["37"]
occurrences = aparisons["20"]
occurrences = aparisons["21"]
```

En ningún lado estás asignando valor a esas llaves en el *hash* `aparisons`, el cual creas con `aparisons = {}`, o bien, un *hash* vacío.

Al parecer estás intentando agregar la llave `element` al *hash*, lo cual puedes lograr con:

```
aparisons[String(element)] = 0
```

También deberías cambiar la siguiente línea:

```
aparisons["element"]=1
```

Pues estás asignando el valor `1` a la llave `"element"`; y parecer que lo que estás intentando es asignarlo a la llave con el nombre igual al elemento correspondiente a la iteración, o bien:

```
aparisons[String(element)] = 1
```

---

En cuanto a tu algoritmo creo que está más complicado de lo que debería, por lo que valdría la pena revisar la lógica (te recomiendo hacer el ejercicio a mano/papel y luego llévalo a código).

Como comentario final, podrías evitar el uso de `String(element)` utilizando el método `to_s`: `element.to_s`; o, mejor aún, utilizar los números como nombres de las llaves, no es necesario convertirlos a *string*; por ejemplo:

```
aparisons[element]
```

Si quieres ver el código modificado (siguiendo tu misma lógica), descubre el siguiente fragmento de código (aunque te recomiendo intentarlo tu antes de verlo):

```html
def delete_nth(elements, max_ocurrences)
  aparisons = Hash.new(0)

  elements.each_with_object([]) do |element, new_array|
    aparisons[element] += 1
    
    if aparisons[element] <= max_ocurrences
      new_array << element
    end
  end
end
```